# Why can a left handed fermion transform into a right handed fermion and vice versa?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, fermions

How (mathematically) can we show a left handed fermion turning into a right handed fermion?

Comment: Chirality is not a good quantum number for massive fermions, i.e. it is not a conserved quantity at all. In fact, the chirality of a massive fermion depends on the observers frame of reference. Therefore, you can't talk about probability of chirality transitions.

Comment: I do not understand your question. The Feynman rules give a perfectly valid interpretation for this process (in fact, it is the *diagrams* which provide a non-mathematical visualization of the mathematics), and the "transformation" is allowed because this is an admissible Feynman diagram. What's the question? (If you don't understand the connection between Feynman diagrams and scattering amplitudes, you should not be asking about specific Feynman diagrams)

Comment: The question (more simply) is, mathematically how do we show a left handed fermion can transform into a right handed fermion?

Comment: @Prahar Chirality is always conserved. You mean handedness. Chirality is a quantum number associated with a Lorentz group representation a given objects tranforms according to. In contrast, handedness gets flipped when we move faster than the particle in question.

Comment: @SamGrill You should specify which mathematical quantity you are really referring to here. Chirality flips in Yukawa interaction, i.e. when a fermion interacts with a Higgs. Handedness gets flipped as soon as we change into frame of reference where the velocity of the particle changes sign, i.e. when we are in a frame that moves faster than the particle in question.

Comment: Fundamentally, fermion fields with spin $\frac{m+n}{2}$ may be represented by $\left(\frac{m+n}{2}, 0\right)$ or by $\left( 0, \frac{m+n}{2}\right)$ (here for simplicity I've omitted the other variants) representations of the Lorentz group, which are obeyed eqs of irreducible representation of Poincare group. You can label the first rep by "left field" while the second rep by "right field". It is very simple to show that these representations are not invariant with respect to $C, P, T$ discrete transformations. That's mathematical reason.